# Apache HTTPS redirect does not work for deep links

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I recently changed my `.htaccess` file on my WordPress blog (hosted by [IONOS](https://www.ionos.com/)) to redirect all incoming traffic to the HTTPS port.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It works fine when I hit the `http://example.com` but deep links (like `http://example.com/posts/1234`) that were previously saved, like for example in bookmarks or Facebook posts, are **not** redirected and are still shows as unsecured. Any ideas?

Comment: What’s with the extra spaces in your condition, and the substituion URL?

Comment: Are you sure those non-working URLs are actually using `example.com` as host name, as your condition demands, and not perhaps `www.example.com` instead?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, my mistake, I edited the code snippet to match my .htaccess